# find the number of elements in the set $\{ x \in S_3 :x^4=e\} ?$

Tags: group-theory

find  the number  of  elements  in the  set $\{ x \in S_3 :x^4=e\} $

**My attempt** : $x^4=e \implies$ order of  $x = 4$

But element of  $S_3$  are $\{I, (12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$ have  no elements  of order $4$
Therefore ,the number  of  elements  in the  set $\{ x \in S_3 :x^4=e\} $ is $0$

Comment: That the fourth power of something is equal to e does not mean that the order is 4. For example, the fourth power of e is e.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  here  e  is the  identity element .  order of $e=1$   so  we  can not write   $e^4=e$   but $e^1=e$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20order%20of,subgroup%20generated%20by%20the%20element.)

Comment: Well, you should probably be reading that page :-) (actually , that page is not particularly good, a good textbook is surely better)

Comment: As indicated by the comment of @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, the issue is not which elements have order $4$, but rather which elements have order $k$, where $k$ is any element in the set $\{1,2,4\}$.  That is, $x^4 = e$ if and only if the order of $x$ is some element in $\{1,2,4\}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  A basic and very useful fact in group theory is that $x^n=e\implies \lvert x\rvert \mid n$.

So here we have $\lvert x\rvert \mid4$.  So $\lvert x\rvert $ can be $1,2$ or $4$.

You're right that $S_3$ has no element of order $4$.  But since $e$ has order $1$ and $(12),(13)$ and $(23)$ have order $2$, they fit the bill.